# Can't upload files from esplorer to nodemcu builds with idf4 and idf5

Tags: esp32, nodemcu, esplorer

I can’t upload a file with esplorer for nodemcu ESP32 builds idf4 and idf5 I made from the GitHub repository, (an idf3 build works fine).

All lua commands in esplorer are working except the file upload. I suspect it has to do with handshaking between spiffs and esplorer but can not pinpoint the problem.
The error I get is: ..Waiting answer from ESP - Timeout reached. Command aborted.

Comment: I've installed nodemcu-tool and tested this with the idf3 build as functional, all downloaded files are there. With the idf5 build installed I could also upload files with the nodemcu-tool but they remain invisible in esplorer and a reboot replies with a 'cannot open init.lua'. Another idf5 build with all the debug checks active in spiffs didn't make my any wiser as there was no feedback on the spiffs behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that idf4 and idf5 firmwares do not support file.write(). If you look at the docs it now uses the io routines. I have not yet found a simple way of uploading lua files to the chip. I have built the latest nodemcu-tool and this looks like it is transferring files but they do not appear in the FS. I have spent hours googling on this and am now going back to idf3.  very frustrating...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes sense now on why its not downloading files. For the moment I also rely on idf3 builds and that is fine but that excludes recent bug fixes. With the info you provide I will look around for a download tool and if found, I'll post it here.